# Is it Possible to Write Class Functions when Declaring a Class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say you have class Foo

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    sayName() {
        console.log('My name is ' + this.name);
    }
}
```

It's possibly to have instance functions like 'sayName'

```js
  new Foo('Kevin').sayName() // My name is Kevin
```

but I would like to have a Class Function.

I can do this:
ie.

```js
  Foo.sayClassName = () => console.log('My Name is Foo')
  Foo.sayClassName() // 'My Name is Foo'
```

But I would like to Declare this when declaring the class. Is this possible?

Comment: `static sayClassName() { console.log(\`My Name is ${this.name}\`); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) method.

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    sayName() {
        console.log('My name is ' + this.name);
    }
    static sayClassName(){
      console.log('My Name is Foo');
    }
}
Foo.sayClassName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the member function is [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static):

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  static sayName() {
    console.log("sayName() called");
  }
}

Foo.sayName()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Static Methods

Static methods are methods directly on the class object (the parent of prototype) and will allow for this behavior. To do this, prefix the method with 'static'. [MDN: `Classes/static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

> The `static` keyword defines a static method or property for a class. Neither static methods nor static properties can be called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself.
>
> Static methods are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects, whereas static properties are useful for caches, fixed-configuration, or any other data you don't need to be replicated across instances.

```js
class Foo {
    constructor() {}
    static bar() { console.log('called'); }
}

Foo.bar(); // prints 'called'
```

### Replicating the behavior

JS classes are just objects with a prototype. For example:

```js
// class Foo {
//     constructor(name) { console.log('Defined: ' + name); this.name = name; }
//     static staticFunc() { console.log('[static]'); }
//     method() { console.log(this.name); }
// }

let Foo = function(name) { console.log('Defined: ' + name); this.name = name; }
Foo.staticFunc = function() { console.log('[static]'); }
Foo.prototype = { method: function() { console.log(this.name); } }
```